# Why is does this report a product type of simple when its not?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Does anyone know why woocommerce is doing this?  I specifically have a bundled product for post ID 1508 as shown.    But then when I try to get the type of 1508 with "$product->get_type();" it says "simple" and not something like "bundled" like I would expect.

Comment: This is the screenshot.  I guess it didn't post it.
http://temp.extremehosting.ca/trash/result.jpg

Comment: Product Bundles are not built into WooCommerce. My guess is it has something to do with the way whatever plugin you are using to create the product bundles implemented this functionality. If you do a `var_dump($product);` Is there anything else you could use to check if it is a "product bundle"

Comment: Nothing at all that says its a bundled product.   I guess its up to this plugin we're using.  I need to extend this somehow:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/bundles/